# Can't connect PowerBelt3D Zero to Print Server

Tags: marlin, octoprint, bigtreetech, belt-printer

I have tried connecting via Repertier, Pronterface, and OctoPrint.  All of them fail to get a response from the handshake attempts.  The OctoPrint "AUTO" setting will automatically try all common BAUDRATE values. Just to be safe, I just tried setting each of the 7 available baudrates manually and then connecting. They all timed out.

The board runs preloaded Marlin firmware, but I don't know much beyond that.  The board is a BTT SKR v1.4 if that helps.

I can run all axis motors and heating elements from the display, and the PC (or RPI) will detect the USB port is active when connected to the printer, so the board seems to be good, I just can't get connected.  There is virtually no support documentation that I can find for getting connected, and I emailed the PowerBelt3D company three days ago but haven't gotten a response, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.